# Numerically integrating a highly oscillatory function

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to evaluate

`NIntegrate[Sin[x] Exp[I m (x + Cos[x] + Sin[x])], {x, 1, 100}]`

with m=1000. The problem is that it's highly oscillatory. What would be the best method to do this integral?

Comment: Add this:`Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 100` to `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk This is still giving me errors for some reason.

Comment: I use `Mathematica 12.1` and for me works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works fast and no warnings

```
ClearAll[x, m];
m = 100;
NIntegrate[Sin[x] Exp[I m (x + Cos[x] + Sin[x])], {x, 1, 100}, MinRecursion -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(actually MinRecursion -> 2 works also, as well as `1`. but `3` looks more cool since it is odd number.)

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

If `m` is an integer, then the integrand is periodic and the trapezoidal rule is a good way to go, except for the leftover bit when the length of the interval is not an exact multiple of the period.

```
i1 = Block[{m = 1000},
   NIntegrate[Sin[x] Exp[I m (x + Cos[x] + Sin[x])],
    {x, 1, 1 + 2 Pi},   (* any period will do *)
    Method -> "Trapezoidal",
    MaxRecursion -> Round[1 + 1.31 Log[m]]] (* theoretically O[Log[m]] *)
   ];

periods = Round[(100 - 1)/(2 Pi)];

i2 = Block[{m = 1000},
   NIntegrate[
    Sin[x] Exp[I m (x + Cos[x] + Sin[x])],
    {x, 1 + periods*2 Pi, 100},
    Method -> {
      "GaussKronrodRule",
      "Points" -> 41}] (* more recursion or more points for larger m *)
   ];

periods*i1 + i2
(*  1.24527 + 0.239249 I  *)
```